# Catching a try error inside an async callback

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using a callback to set some ip's on redis db async.

I'm trying to catch the error and send it through express to my error handler middleware.

I'm generating an error on purpose on the select method, but it doesn't catch my error.

See following code:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const redis = require('redis')
  const client = redis.createClient()
  try {
    client.select('2d', (err) => { // instead of 2 number, i use '2d' string, to generate an error on purpose
      const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
      client.set(ip, true, 'EX', 120, (err, rep) => {
        return next()
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    err.type = 'SilentSystem'
    next(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation of the redis npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis), it's clear that it uses standard Node-style callbacks. In a standard Node-style callback, the first argument passed to the callback you provide is either an error or `null`; that's where and how errors are reported. (You've even defined a parameter called `err` in your code.) They can't be caught by a `try/catch` because control has already passed out of the `try/catch` (and in fact out of the function it's in) long before the error occurs.

So you'd handle it like this:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const redis = require('redis')
  const client = redis.createClient()
  client.select('2d', (err) => { // instead of 2 number, i use '2d' string, to generate an error on purpose
    if (err) {
      // Handle error here
      err.type = 'SilentSystem'
      next(err)
    } else {
      // Handle success here
      const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
      client.set(ip, true, 'EX', 120, (err, rep) => {
        if (err) {
          err.type = 'SilentSystem'
          next(err)
        } else {
          next()
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> My actual code is a bit more complex so I was trying to avoid calling to avoid repeating calling `if(err)` and `next(err)` by using `try`. What's a better way (less verbose) to handle errors here?

Unfortunately, that's the nature of Node-style callbacks. One option is to give yourself a filtering function you pass all those results through so your common error-handling code is there.

**But**: You might consider using a lib that "promisifies" Node-style callbacks so you can use promises instead, complete with their chaining mechanism which makes centralized error handling possible. (One such package is [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify), but there are others.) With "promisified" versions of `client.select`, `client.set`., etc., that code could look like this:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const redis = require('redis')
  const client = makeNiftyPromiseVersionOf(redis.createClient())
  client.select('2d')
    .then(data => {
      const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
      return client.set(ip, true, 'EX', 120)
    })
    .then(() => {
      next()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      err.type = 'SilentSystem'
      next(err)
    })
}
```

Note how the error handling is consolidated at the end; if there's an error in `client.select`, the `then` callback is skipped and control passes to the `catch`. If not, the `then` callback is executed and `client.set` is performed, and any errors from it will also go to that `catch`.

This also opens the door to using ES2017's `async`/`await` to write asynchronous code in a synchronous style:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  (async () => {
    const redis = require('redis')
    const client = makeNiftyPromiseVersionOf(redis.createClient())
    try {
      const data = await client.select('2d');
      const ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
      await client.set(ip, true, 'EX', 120)
      next()
    } catch (err) {
      err.type = 'SilentSystem'
      next(err)
    }
  })();
}
```

---

Side note: I would remove the `require` call *out* of the exported function, and instead do it at the module level:

```
const redis = require('redis')
module.exports = {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: My actual code is a bit more complex so I was trying to avoid calling if(err) and then returning next(err) by using try. What's a better way (less verbose) to handle errors here?

Comment: *Trying to avoid repeating calling if(err) and next(err) that should read

Comment: @S.Schenk: Unfortunately, that's the nature of Node-style callbacks. I've added to the end of the answer with one suggestion.

Comment: Going over your first block of code I would also add another if and return next(err) at the client.set call. It also demonstrate better why you should avoid callbacks.

Comment: @S.Schenk: Quite so, done. But note that we're still using callbacks in the promise-based solution too (and in some sense, under the covers in the `async`/`await` solution). It's just more consolidated and composable, etc.

Comment: Also the else after returning next(err) seems redundant. *edit: Actually I've just checked and it isn't. Seems that calling next does not break. I assume I can just return next then instead of using else.

Comment: @S.Schenk: I don't see any `else` after a `return next`.

Comment: you are right I meant to write the else after the next not return next. But calling just next does not break so I guess I can just return next(err) rather then just calling next(err) with else.

Comment: @S.Schenk: You *can*, but it's semantically misleading. The return value of the callback is not used for anything.